# Fileupload required doesn't work

Tags: html

I got form and on submit my fileupload let me pass when there is no file even when io set required property on it:/ Can someone tell me what is wrong with this?

```
<input class="fileUpload" name="file" type="file" multiple required"/>
```

Comment: What browser are you testing it in?

Comment: `<input class="fileUpload required" name="file" type="file" multiple />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<form action="action.php">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" required multiple>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

i think last `"` is the problem , it is working to me [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: 2nd question this class dosn't load on other browsers then Chrome
.ula{
background-image:url('images/ula.png');
height:300px;
background-repeat-x:no-repeat;
background-repeat-y:no-repeat;
}

bg repeat seems to not work any idea?

Comment: Hi @Alex post it as a new question

Comment: do you want the image need to be repeat ? if yes check it herehttp://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Comment: i want it to not repeat :)

Comment: post it as a new question, that would be better